# how to do automatic backup of running vmware virtual machine?

Tags: backup, vmware

I want to do

- regular
- **automatic**
- backup of my vmware virtual machine (16GB big, Windows XP)
- that is **running**

I do not have an access to ESX admin. I can ask our admin to set up something in the admin area but I do not have access for myself.

I have installed few programs that are important to me so I want to have working backup at any point of time.

Note:
I know I can copy all the files when the virtual machine is not up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't ask them do it for you?

You can get reference and download a free backup script [here](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760)

Comment: wow,that loooooks good...